# How to authenticate within Azure ML pipeline and avoid browser interactive authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

I have created a very simple azure ml pipeline. Basically, it accesses data through an api and prints it.
I have tried using a ClientSecretCredential and a ServicePrincipalAuthentication but the pipeline still asks me for a web browser authentication to continue (even though the script runs when I just run the python file in the terminal)

```
    from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget, AmlCompute
    import azureml.core
    from azureml.core import Workspace, Datastore
    from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
    from azureml.core.authentication import ServicePrincipalAuthentication
    
    
    ws = Workspace.from_config()
    
    keyvault = ws.get_default_keyvault()
    
    client_id = keyvault.get_secret("ClientID")
    tenant_id = keyvault.get_secret("TENANTID")
    secret_id = keyvault.get_secret("CLIENTSECRET")
    
    sp = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id = tenant_id, client_id = client_id, client_secret = secret_id)

#  sp = ServicePrincipalAuthentication(tenant_id, client_id, secret_id)
```

This is the output from the pipeline:

2022-07-06 06:08:21,496|azureml._vendor.azure_cli_core._session|INFO|Failed to load or parse file /root/.azureml/auth/azureProfile.json. It will be overridden by default settings.
2022-07-06 06:08:21,496|azureml._vendor.azure_cli_core._session|INFO|Failed to load or parse file /root/.azureml/auth/az.json. It will be overridden by default settings.
2022-07-06 06:08:21,496|azureml._vendor.azure_cli_core._session|INFO|Failed to load or parse file /root/.azureml/auth/az.sess. It will be overridden by default settings.
2022-07-06 06:08:21,498|azureml._vendor.azure_cli_core|DEBUG|Current cloud config:
AzureCloud
2022-07-06 06:08:21,501|azureml._vendor.azure_cli_core|DEBUG|Current cloud config:
AzureCloud
2022-07-06 06:08:21,527|azureml._vendor.azure_cli_core._profile|INFO|No web browser is available. Fall back to device code.
**2022-07-06 06:08:21,628|azureml._vendor.azure_cli_core.auth.identity|WARNING|To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code XXXXXXXXXX to authenticate.**
2022-07-06 06:08:49,950|azureml.core.authentication|DEBUG|Time to expire 1814345.049124 seconds

What can I do for it to pick up the credential in the code and avoid asking for interactive authentication?

Answer (score 0):

By default, authentication procedure is **UI Based (Browser interactive based)**. To avoid that kind of authentication, we need to look over either one of the following:

- Azure CLI based - [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/)
- Service Principal based
- MSI (Managed Service Identity based)
- Azure ML Token based.

The above 4 alternative procedures which can avoid the browser interactive based authentication.

There are different **classes** for authentication as mentioned in [Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.authentication?view=azure-ml-py#classes)

To know more about different methods in authentication follow the [repo](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/manage-azureml-service/authentication-in-azureml/authentication-in-azureml.ipynb)